# Using awk to generate report from apache http logs

Tags: linux, bash, apache, awk

Hoping someone can help me with a bash linux script to generate report from http logs.

Logs format:

```
domain.com 101.100.144.34 - r.c.bob [14/Feb/2017:11:31:20 +1100] "POST /webmail/json HTTP/1.1" 200 1883 "https://example.domain.com/webmail/index-rui.jsp?v=1479958955287" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" 1588 2566 "110.100.34.39" 9FC1CC8A6735D43EF75892667C08F9CE 84670 - - - -
```

Output require:

```
time in epoch,host,Resp Code,count  

1485129842,101.100.144.34,200,4000  
1485129842,101.101.144.34,404,1889
```

what I have so far but nothing near what I am trying to achieve:

```
tail -100 httpd_access_*.log | awk '{print  $5 " " $2 " " $10}' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Are the logs continuously growing in content? You may want to disable buffering in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{
   # print header
   print "time in epoch,host,Resp Code,count"
   # prepare month conversion array
   split( "Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jui Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec", tmp)
   for (i in tmp) M[tmp[i]]=i
   }

   {
   #prepare time conversion for mktime() using array and substitution
   # from 14/Feb/2017:11:31:20 +1100
   # to YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]
   split( $5, aT, /[:/[:blank:]]/)
   t = $5; sub( /^.*:|:/, " ", t)
   t = aT[3] " " M[aT[2]] " " aT[1] t

   # count (not clear if it s this to count due to time changing
   Count[ sprintf( "%s, %s, %s", mktime( t), $2, $10)]++
   }

   END{
      # disply the result counted
      for( e in Count) printf( "%s, %d\n", e, Count[e])
      }
   ' httpd_access_*.log
```

- count is to be more specificaly describe to be sure about the criteria to count
- need GNU awk for mktime() function
- assume time is always in this format
- no secure nor filter (not the purpose of this)

Answer (score 0):

Sure the pure AWK based solution above would be much faster, and more complete.
But can also be done in smaller steps:

First get date and convert it to EPOCH:

```
$ dt=$(awk '{print $5,$6}' file.log)
$ ep=$(date -d "$(sed -e 's,/,-,g' -e 's,:, ,' <<<"${dt:1:-1}")" +"%s")
$ echo "$ep"
1487032280
```

Since now you have the epoch date in the bash var $ep, you can continue with your initiall awk like this:

```
$ awk -v edt=$ep '{print edt","$2","$10}' file.log
1487032280,101.100.144.34,200
```

If you want a header , you can just print one before last awk with a simple echo.